# How to retrieve changes in default community login page via ANT?

Tags: community, metadata-api, customer-community, ant, login

I'm having a small issue retrieving changes in a community.

I have a customer community in which I use the standard or default login page. I changed the logo and the colors of the standard page in workspaces > administration > login and registration, and it looks like this:

[image: Login page of community in my Sandbox]

But when I retrieve the community metadata, and deploy the community to other sandbox, it doesn't have this changes in the destination sandbox, ithas the default salesforce logo and colors.

[image: Login page in destination sandbox]

In my package.xml I have all the types that the documentation says. I have all these types:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SiteDotCom</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Portal</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

So, I wanted to know, what thing should I add to the package.xml to get the changes on the standard login page using ANT? What am I missing? where can I find these changes?

Thanks for the help and for the time reading my question, any help is appreciated. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

at the end I discovered how to recover that changes if anyone else is having problems with this as I was.

I found that there's a type for adding to the package.xml **called 'NetworkBranding'** and those changes are stored inside it.

For example, what I used to retrieve my changes was

```
<types>
    <members>cbClient_Portal</members>
    <name>NetworkBranding</name>
</types>
```

That recovered the configuration that I did to the standard login page. I think that this type admits the usage of a * wildcard if you don't know what name should you put on it.

For finding that I had to use this page that automatically prints out a package.xml with all the metadata elements that it found in your org (production or sandbox). **This is the link:**

https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/

Thanks for all the help. Hope this can help someone in the future.

Comment: Noted! I thought you needed the Fleipage of login !!! Thanks for sharing back!!!

Comment: glad to be of help Mohith!